# New Close Reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

The moderators recently added a new close reason to the Off-Topic list:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers.

This was adapted from the [new reason on the main Stack Overflow site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow).  The only difference is that we removed the "This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting." part, as this is either difficult in some cases on the site, or it doesn't make sense.  We may decide to add modified version of this back in.

This close reason is an attempt to have a default that aligns with the true intent of the old "too localized" reason that sites [used to have](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/).  This reason should really only be used for typos, non-problems, and other similar questions *that won't help future readers*.  For example, I closed this one with this reason:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63935/webform-add-more-button-not-showing

This question ended up being a non-problem, and the module was working as expected.

Please use this new close reason wisely.

### 2014-03-26:

This was revised to

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be
>   reproduced, **was solved by a cache clear**, or was a simple typographical
>   error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was
>   resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

emphasis mine to show the change.

Comment: I have missed the old "too localized" on a number of occasions. :)

Comment: you closed a very old question, will it notify to op?

Comment: @Bala It should.  There was a recent flag on it, which brought it to my attention.